# How to make the WinForms ToolTip.Show method not display the previous tooltip string for a fraction of second?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await, tooltip

I encountered this issue while trying to make a custom tooltip system for the custom hit-testing system of OxyPlot. The sample code is below, it moves the mouse cursor automatically when handling the event `Form.Click` to show the problem.

### Steps to reproduce

1. create an empty Form (example size: 500x500)
2. handle the Click event of the Form
3. on Click

   1. show the tooltip string "test 1"
   2. move the mouse
   3. hide the tooltip
   4. wait a few seconds
   5. show the tooltip string two-line "test 123456789\n\nanother line"

For a fraction of second the one-line "test 1" string is shown in the last cursor position too.

### Screen recording (the issue is not visible in it)

[image: screen recording]

### Code

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ToolTip toolTip;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Click += Form1_Click;

        toolTip = new ToolTip();
        toolTip.UseAnimation = false;
        toolTip.UseFading = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _ = DoIt();
    }

    private async Task DoIt()
    {
        Point pos = PointToClient(MousePosition);
        pos.Y += Cursor.Current.Size.Height;

        // Without the -2000, the duration of the tooltip is too long (because of the fade-in/out animation)
        toolTip.Show("test", this, pos, Math.Max(0, toolTip.AutoPopDelay - 2000));

        await Task.Delay(5000);

        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 100, Cursor.Position.Y);

        toolTip.Hide(this);

        Application.DoEvents();

        await Task.Delay(5000);


        pos = PointToClient(MousePosition);
        pos.Y += Cursor.Current.Size.Height;

        toolTip.Show("test 123456789\n\nanother line", this, pos, Math.Max(0, toolTip.AutoPopDelay - 2000));
    }
}
```

### What I tried

I made the code sample above to show the issue... I have also searched on StackOverflow and did not find something to help me.

### Expected result

The second tooltip shows like the first tooltip, without a flashing image of the previous tooltip string.

### Actual result

The old tooltip string flashes in the place of the new tooltip string. It is not very visible, mostly when the animations are enabled, but it is still ugly to me.

### Ideas of possible solutions

1. Use a Timer or some trick with async-await.
2. Create two alternating ToolTip objects.

### System configuration

I use for this .NET Framework v4.5.2 but I have tried the code above with .NET Framework v4.7.2 and it has the same problem. I use Windows 10 and VS 2019.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party, but anyhow.

The solution is to simply **instantiate a new ToolTip component each time you want to display one**.  That's it, no flicking of the previous text anymore.  (You might want to dispose the old one to make sure there are no leaks.)